# Riverpod - State notifier to get current user is always null

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have this state notifier to get the current user:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final userProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, User?>((ref) {
  return UserNotifier(null);
});

class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<User?> {
  UserNotifier(User? state) : super(state) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        clearUser();
      } else {
        setUser(user);
      }
    });
  }

  void setUser(User user) {
    state = user;
  }

  void clearUser() {
    state = null;
  }
}
```

I use it in my Http client to get the id token:

```
final Provider<Dio> httpClientProvider = Provider<Dio>((ref) {
  final dio = Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: EnvironmentConstants.of().apiUrl));
  final localDataSource = ref.read(localStorageDataSourceProvider);
  final user = ref.read(userProvider);

  String? accessToken = localDataSource.get<dynamic>(
      keyToRead: 'access_token')['access_token_value'] as String?;

  accessToken = accessToken ?? user?.getIdToken() as String;
```

The thing is the value of `user` is always null in the HttpProvider.

So `final user = ref.read(userProvider);` always returns null.

`FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen(` shows it is populated but it is also running too often:

[image]

I think this bit is always setting it back to null as it is also running too often:

```
final userProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, User?>((ref) {
  return UserNotifier(null);
});
```

I'm not sure what I could pass into there instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Made the instance of the state notifier a global variable so it doesn't re-instantiate it when something calls the `ref.read(userProvider)`:

```
var currentUser = UserNotifier();

final userProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, User?>((ref) {
  return currentUser;
});
```

Very open to suggestions for improvement as I'm not strictly sure if this is meant to be done... Can I achieve the same outcome without a global variable?